# How does "The Death of Chaos" prevent the world of Recluce from being destroyed?

Tags: l-e-modesitt, saga-of-recluce

In *The Death of Chaos*, L.E. Modesitt Jr's chronologically final book in the *Saga of Recluce* series, Lerris destroys an enormous Hamorian fleet attempting to take Recluce.

Hamor, being mostly independent of the order/chaos conflicts occurring in the world, was able to invent technology to create machines to allow them to rise above all other nations - including Recluce - in both commerce and war. What the Hamorians either did not know, or chose to ignore, was that machines (including simple ones like rifles) implicitly create order. Thus by building vast numbers of such machines, Hamor created massive amounts of order that, due to the Balance between order and chaos, resulted in equally massive amounts of chaos being generated.

However this "machine order" and "machine chaos" are somehow different to that embodied by living beings (including mages), with the result that the chaos thus created manifested in the core of the world on which the Saga takes place, instead of creating vastly more powerful chaos mages. This incredible increase in chaos began to jeopardize the existence of that world; by destroying most of Hamor's machine-ordered fleet by channelling the chaos the fleet had created by its very existence, essentially cancelling the two parts out, Lerris prevented his world's destruction while satisfying the Balance, and everyone lived happily ever after.

Except... Hamor is still around, and the technology they've created isn't going away. The history of the Saga has demonstrated Hamor to be a very patient, pragmatic and resilient nation, and there is absolutely nothing stopping them from rebuilding their fleet - with the resultant creation of chaos again. And since it's implied that a side-effect of what Lerris has done precludes the existence of new powerful order or chaos mages in future, there will be no more mages to stop future Hamor from building enough ordered machines to cause the world to destroy itself.

Has Lerris merely delayed the inevitable, or has he changed the nature of and/or the Balance between order and chaos, such that technology no longer affects order and chaos? (In which case, Hamor will eventually win unless Recluce and Candar unite against it.)